# Can't import font-awesome in React JS

Tags: reactjs, npm, font-awesome

I'm learning React JS and I'm trying to import font-awesome with npm modules to display this icon:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Like extends Component {
  render() {
    return <i class="far fa-heart"></i>;
  }
}

export default Like;
```

How the "import" statement at the top of the file should look like for this icon? I tried to read official documentation but can't really understand the pattern...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the required modules are installed

```
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
$ npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular
```

you can use them like

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHeart } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular';

class Like extends Component {
  render() {
    return <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart}/>;
  }
}

export default Like;
```

For more details refer to the [official github repo](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome)

In case you're a pro member, you can install other modules as well, the listed once are free for use.

To have both types available, you can do import alias

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faHeart as regularHeart } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular';
import { faHeart as solidHeart } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

class Like extends Component {
  render() {
    return {this.props.solid ? <FontAwesomeIcon icon={solidHeart}/> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={regularHeart}/>};
  }
}

export default Like;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Do I understand correctly that every time the name of needed icon contains "-" we need to use camel case typing like so = "fa-heart -> faHeart" ?

Comment: Correct, also note that the regular (non solid) icons are in a separate module `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular`

Comment: Got it! And also, how would I add second class "far" to "faHeart"? Because currently it displays a solid icon and "far" should make it appear with some space inside.

Comment: That's what I meant, use `@fortawesome/fontawesome-free-regular` instead

Comment: https://fontawesome.com/icons/heart?style=regular - there is a regular version(which I need) and a solid version. How can I access the regular one?

Comment: I updated the answer, it now takes the regular version

Comment: Now I see what you meant, it's very clear now. I have one more question if you don't mind. The whole idea is to make the regular version transform to solid one when a user clicks on it. If both versions are located in two separate modules, how can I make it possible? At the beginning I was thinking about conditional class additing, but now I don't really see how I can make it work

Comment: You can use import alias and import both, then do a conditional include

Comment: Understood, thank you so much for you help, very much appreciated! :)