# React unicode icons not showing when importing fontawesome in style.scss

Tags: reactjs, font-awesome

here I have a working codepen using HTML, where the icons (Plus) are shown. In the HTML header there is fontawesome directly imported.
https://codepen.io/jartysharky/pen/YzQvzrv

No I want to use these Icons without HMTL.
In my App.js I have the following to import my styles and link to the component:

```
import './assets/scss/style.scss';

    const App = () => {
        return (
            <Router>
                <PageScrollTop>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/"}`} exact component={Form}/>
```

Then in the Form component I got my main form content that can be seen in the codepen.
Because the .scss is imported in the App.js, I also got all my styles in the Form.js. My problem is that the icons are not shown and are only rectangles.
Because there is no HTML I can't simply import fontawesome in the head, so I decided to import it directly in my style.sccs.

I have tried using `@import "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css";` in my style.scss but the icons seem not to be found
How do I need to import fontawesome in my css files so that they get recognized?

When I import several icons into the component I can use them regularly using their names in React, but I need to be able to use the unicodes of the icons in the css part.

```
  ul.ks-cboxtags li label::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 2px 6px 2px 2px;
    content: "\f067";
    transition: transform .3s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't import font-awesome in React JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62578444/cant-import-font-awesome-in-react-js)

Comment: I know how to use the npm module, but as far as I know I can use these icons only directly in the component. I need to use the unicode icons in my style.scss like they were normally imported for example in the head of a html file. Because there is no html file, I imported the external icon css into my styles.scss, which is then imported to my App.js. Still the icons dont show

Comment: You can add that link to the HTML in the public folder